# Run a active scan from OWASP ZAP through Ubuntu command line using Open API Definition

Tags: linux-kernel, openapi, owasp, zap, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to run a active scan from OWASP ZAP using only my Ubuntu(22.04) terminal by importing a external open API definition. This can be easily done through the GUI, but I need to do the same process using only command line. I didn't found a proper documentation to follow either.

I have tried following structure of the command to do the active scan, but seems it fails.

```
/path/to/zap.sh -daemon -openapifile /path/to/swagger.json  -openapitargeturl /path/to/targetUrl -quickout /path/to/output.html
```

Can anyone suggest a proper way to make this active scan through the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: There is some documentation here: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/?python#api-catalogue

Answer (score 1):

We have lots of documentation for automating ZAP - see https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/
I recommend looking at the API packaged scan and the Automation Framework.

Comment: But I need to make the active scan only through cmd. I found a library, [zap-cli](https://github.com/Grunny/zap-cli) which can run the active scans. But I need to know whether it is a good solution?

Comment: The zap-cli library is a third party tool which is no longer maintained. I do not think it is a good solution. Both the packaged scans and automation framework can be run from the command line.